# Typesetting RC Network

Tags: circuitikz

Can anybody help me write latex `circuitikz` code to draw this RC ladder network with 11 elements please?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  The stack exchange is not a coding service, even if it sometimes functions that way.  The site works best to solve discrete definable problems.  If you have a first attempt at creating your circuitikz, then we'd be happy to help you get past where you're stuck.  If you don't know where to begin, then I'd suggest one of many internet tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is pretty redundant and doesn't need a lot of code, here you go. Just draw it once, and then do it multiple times using `\foreach` using two temporary coordinates and relative placement.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    (0,0) to[R=$R_a$] (++2,0)
    \foreach\n in {b,c,d,e,f}
      {
        coordinate(tmp1) to[short,*-] ++(0,0.75)
        to[R=$R_{\n}$] ++(2,0) coordinate(tmp2)
        to[short,-*] (tmp2|-tmp1) coordinate(tmp2)
        (tmp1) to[short] ++(0,-0.75) coordinate(tmp1)
        to[C,l_=$C_{\n}$] (tmp1-|tmp2)
        to[short] (tmp2)
        to[short] ++(1,0)
      }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir for your help